# Counting number of rows in Query with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to count the number of rows in a table, but i am getting the following error:

> sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Here is my SQL:

```
<?php   
    $getPriceRequests = "SELECT * FROM PriceRequests";
    $resultPricerequests = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getPriceRequests);
    $priceRequests = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultPricerequests, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);  

    $numPriceRequests = sqlsrv_num_rows($priceRequests);
?>
```

But for some reason when i print out the following i get the above error:

```
<?php echo $numPriceRequests; ?>
```

Comment: use the `$resultPricerequests` as argument

Comment: I have done but now i am not getting any result what so ever?

Comment: have a look at the first example http://php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php

Comment: and maybe you must call `sqlsrv_num_rows($resultPricerequests)` before fetching any row. But I don't know. Never used the ms sql extension.

Comment: Great, its working thanks! Put it as an answer so i can vote for you as best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed code to the following for the desired result:

```
<?php   
    $getPriceRequests = "SELECT * FROM PriceRequests";
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $resultPriceRequests = sqlsrv_query($sapconn2, $getPriceRequests, $params, $options);
    $numPriceRequests = sqlsrv_num_rows($resultPriceRequests);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of rows in the table, then do that in the database, not the application.

The correct query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM PriceRequests
```

Then read the value back into the application.

Comment: You are right. But if you make an request like the one in the question and you want to know how many rows are in this result you should feed the `sqlsrv_num_rows` with the request.